Adding non-contiguous free space into partition (resize) using cfdisk
I want to increase my main Ubuntu partition from 27.1GB to 59.1GB using free space on my hard drive. I seem to have some missing sectors between the partitions which means I am unable to extend it into the free space I allocated in my virtual machine. How to I find and reallocate those missing sectors using the CLI?
cfdisk gives
                                 Disk: /dev/sda
          Size: 59.2 GiB, 63564677120 bytes, 124149760 sectors
      Label: gpt, identifier: ABB94AF0-B8D2-419B-8E7B-DACD89C05D7B

Device              Start          End    Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sda1          227328     57040862   56813535   27.1G Linux filesystem  
/dev/sda14           2048        10239       8192      4M BIOS boot
/dev/sda15          10240       227327     217088    106M EFI System
Free space       57040896    124149726   67108831     32G

The end sector of /dev/sda1 is 57040862 and the start sector of the free space is 57040896. When I try to resize /dev/sda1 I get:
Maximum size is 29088529920 bytes.

lsblk gives
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0     7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1     7:1    0    64M  1 loop /snap/core20/2379
loop2     7:2    0  63.7M  1 loop /snap/core20/2434
loop3     7:3    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/1663
loop4     7:4    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/1722
loop5     7:5    0   273M  1 loop /snap/firefox/5273
loop6     7:6    0   274M  1 loop /snap/firefox/5361
loop7     7:7    0 505.1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop8     7:8    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop9     7:9    0    87M  1 loop /snap/lxd/29351
loop10    7:10   0  89.4M  1 loop /snap/lxd/31333
loop11    7:11   0  38.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
loop12    7:12   0  44.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/23258
sda       8:0    0  59.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0  27.1G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                 /
├─sda14   8:14   0     4M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0   106M  0 part /boot/efi
sdb       8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1    8:17   0 931.5G  0 part 
sr0      11:0    1     4M  0 rom  

